# How to display picture from field near every blog entry

Tags: 7

When I go into mywebsite/blog I have blog entries displayed. What I want to do, is display a picture uploaded to every blog entry left to the entries displayed on this page. How can I achieve this? Is there some code to display uploaded picture in page--blog.tpl.php? I also would like to NOT display picture when someone actually click and goes to some single blog entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with standard field visibility.

Add an image field to your blog type.

Then click on display fields, you can have it displaying for teaser view, and hidden in the full view.